# The trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `[u16]`

Tags: rust

I have a function that converts a wide string array as a `[u16]` to a `String`.

```
fn get_string_from_wide(wide_array: &[u16]) -> Result<String, String> {
    let trimmed_wide = wide_array.iter()
            .position(|char| *char == 0)
            .map(|i| &wide_array[..i]) //<- remove `&` will give the error as the title
            .unwrap_or(wide_array);
    let os_str = OsString::from_wide(trimmed_wide);

    os_str
        .into_string()
        .or(Err("Could not convert `Os_String` to `String`".to_string()))
}
```

Although the parameter is passed by reference, I still get the type as `[u16]` instead of `&[u16]`

If I remove the `&` the code compiles, but I don't want to pass a reference of a reference.

Is the var `wide_array` actually the data itself and not a reference as stated in the function parameter, and thus I still need to take a reference with `&` for referenced function calls? Or is it actually a reference to it?

Comment: *I don't want to pass a reference of a reference.* — why do you think you have a reference to a reference?

Comment: because I have the parameter as reference of [u16] and passing the reference of this parameter which is a reference by itself to the method `position`. am I wrong?

Comment: *the parameter as reference of [u16]* — yes, it is. *passing the reference of this parameter [...] to the method position* — where do you believe this is happening?

Comment: ohh sorry I mean `map` function

Comment: where indicated by the comment in the code above

Comment: Ok then, your issue should be answered by the duplicates. `foo[..]` does not return a reference, so `&foo[..]` is a single reference.

Comment: does this mean that `wide_array` var in line 2 is not reference? if so what is the purpose of the `&` then in function parameter?

Comment: If you mean `wide_array` in `wide_array.iter`, that's still a slice, which is a type of reference; it's the argument passed in. There's no `[..]` on that line.

Comment: I think i got it, so the use of `[..]` implies the use of `&`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141677/discussion-between-musunaji-and-shepmaster).